# Query is not joining correctly, how do I fix it?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a large query that is structured like this:

There are a bunch of tables the main table `LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS` has a `t_dt` column.

There is `LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE` that has a `season` value.

There is also `TR_SEASON` has a `season` value of its own (corresponding to the `LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE`) it also has a `start_dt` and `end_dt` fields

What I want to say in my query is that the join has to be `p.season` field has to correspond to the `a.t_dt` date falls in between `tr_season` `start_dt` and `end_dt` and i don't know how to do this.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this correctly.

**Tables**

tr_season

```
season desc    start_dt   end_dt
1     s1      1/1/2013   12/31/2013
2     s2      1/1/2014   12/31/2014
3     s3      1/1/2015   12/31/2015
```

LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE

```
season  price1   price2   price3
1        4         5        7
1        2         6        8     
1        7         5        9
```

LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS

```
t_dt      count
2/5/2013    6
2/7/2014    2
8/2/2015    3
```

Season's get matched up and counts will be multiplied by pricing.

My query (unfinished)

```
select * -- a bunch of stuff 
FROM LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN lv_customer_info1 b         on a.grp_attending = b.customer_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN lv_chc_order_detail_info o  on a.order_no = o.order_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE p   on /*this is where i'm stuck*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
select * -- a bunch of stuff 
FROM LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN lv_customer_info1 b         on a.grp_attending = b.customer_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN lv_chc_order_detail_info o  on a.order_no = o.order_no 
JOIN TR_SEASON s     on a.t_dt between s.start_dt and s.end_dt
JOIN LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE p   on s.id = p.season
```

This way you can look at your `t_dt` field and it should be between the `start_dt` and `end_dt` and then use the id in that field for your join.

Comment: This works, Thank you. I wonder though if adding an extra join can drastically decrease the efficiency/speed.

Answer (score 0):

Without a database to work with for testing, I think you're looking for something similar to the following. I'm not exactly a SQL expert, but I think something like this would work.

```
select * -- a bunch of stuff 
FROM LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN lv_customer_info1 b         on a.grp_attending = b.customer_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN lv_chc_order_detail_info o  on a.order_no = o.order_no 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE p   on p.season = (
    SELECT season 
    FROM tr_season s 
    INNER JOIN LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE pr 
    ON pr.season = s.season
    WHERE (s.start_dt < pr.t_dt AND s.end_dt > pr.t_dt)
)
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN LTR_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE pr` the price table doesn't have the `t_dt` fields it only has the `pr.season` fields.

Comment: My apologies, I must have gotten those mixed up. If you need to make sure the LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_CS t_dt field falls between the seasons date fields, there needs to be some sort of relation there. Are there any other fields on these tables or any other tables that could link them?